# Iterating rows of a Spark Dataset and applying operations in Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

New to Spark (2.4.x) and using the **Java** API (*not* Scala!!!)

I have a `Dataset` that I've read in from a CSV file. It has a schema (named columns) like so:

```
id (integer)  |  name (string)  |  color (string)  |  price (double)  |  enabled (boolean)
```

An example row:

```
23 | "hotmeatballsoup" | "blue" | 3.95 | true
```

There are *many* (tens of thousands) rows in the dataset. I would like to write an expression using the proper **Java**/Spark API, that scrolls through each row and applies the following two operations on each row:

1. If the price is `null`, default it to `0.00`; and then
2. If the color column value is "red", add `2.55` to the price

Since I'm so new to Spark I'm not sure even where to begin! My best attempt thus far is definitely wrong, but its a least a starting point I guess:

```
Dataset csvData = sparkSession.read()
    .format("csv")
    .load(fileToLoad.getAbsolutePath());

// ??? get rows somehow
Seq<Seq<String>> csvRows = csvData.getRows(???, ???);

// now how to loop through rows???
for (Seq<String> row : csvRows) {
    // how apply two operations specified above???
    if (row["price"] == null) {
        row["price"] = 0.00;
    }

    if (row["color"].equals("red")) {
        row["price"] = row["price"] + 2.55;
    }
}
```

Can someone help nudge me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use spark sql api to achieve it. Null values could also be replaced with values using `.fill()` from `DataFrameNaFunctions`. Otherwise you could convert Dataframe to Dataset and do these steps in `.map`, but sql api is better and more efficient in this case.

```
+---+---------------+-----+-----+-------+
| id|           name|color|price|enabled|
+---+---------------+-----+-----+-------+
| 23|hotmeatballsoup| blue| 3.95|   true|
| 24|            abc|  red|  1.0|   true|
| 24|            abc|  red| null|   true|
+---+---------------+-----+-----+-------+
```

import sql functions before class declaration:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
```

sql api:

```
df.select(
        col("id"), col("name"), col("color"),
        when(col("color").equalTo("red").and(col("price").isNotNull()), col("price").plus(2.55))
        .when(col("color").equalTo("red").and(col("price").isNull()), 2.55)
        .otherwise(col("price")).as("price")
        ,col("enabled")
).show();
```

or using temp view and sql query:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df");
spark.sql("select id,name,color, case when color = 'red' and price is not null then (price + 2.55) when color = 'red' and price is null then 2.55 else price end as price, enabled from df").show();
```

output:

```
+---+---------------+-----+-----+-------+
| id|           name|color|price|enabled|
+---+---------------+-----+-----+-------+
| 23|hotmeatballsoup| blue| 3.95|   true|
| 24|            abc|  red| 3.55|   true|
| 24|            abc|  red| 2.55|   true|
+---+---------------+-----+-----+-------+
```